# PDO connection refuses access

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to add some records to my database using PDO to make my code more secure.
But it gives me a connection error:

```
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The connection file includes two scripts, one is regular mysql and second one is my new PDO. The first one is working well, but the PDO throws an error.
Am I doing something wrong over here?

EDIT: CODE DELETED DUE TO SOME SHIEET

Comment: Does the normal mysql connect correctly ?

Comment: Yes it does connect correctly

Comment: As I see you are also trying to create an PDO please only worry about this comment if you use the `mysql`functions only for testing and not for live use: Please try to avoid using the `mysql` functions as they are deprecated. Use the `mysqli` functions instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first connection is to `127.0.0.1`, while your second connections is to `localhost`.

They might be the same, but from the server (mysql) side they are not. Use 127.0.0.1 in your PDO line and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I have noticed it but the change didn't help

Comment: Please update your code if it is not the exact code you run. Furthermore - the error you put there is for `'root'@'localhost'`. It is for sure not the error that you get, since you tried to login using the user `15641733_mu`. If you really get that error - it seems like your application tired to access using the `root` user, and you should check why.

Comment: @Mateusz, congratulations, but please change your question to be helpful to other users with same problem...

Comment: I will do this as i get home. I noticed something worrying so i edited the first post